# How to wrap mutliple queries into a single where clause in laravel

Tags: laravel, filter, eloquent, where-clause, clause

I want to fetch records from a table `pasien_polis` where `polyclinic_id` matches the `id` of the `polyclinics` table.

I can achieve that by doing this:

```
    $polyclinic = Polyclinic::findOrFail($id);
    $pasienpoli = Polyclinic::find($id)->PasienPoli;
```

the next thing I want to filter is the `created_at` records, I only want to fetch records created today.
This query works well:

```
    $pasienpoli = DB::table('pasien_polis')->whereDate('created_at', '=', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString())->get();
```

the problem came up when I wanted to combine those two filters into a single where clause.

I have tried the following but it returns `NULL`:

```
$polyclinic = Polyclinic::findOrFail($id);
$match = Polyclinic::find($id)->PasienPoli;

$pasienpoli = DB::table('pasien_polis')->where([
                     ['polyclinic_id', '=', '$match'],
                     ['created_at', '=', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString()]
                                               ])->get();
```

Any help please?

UPDATE:

[image: STRUCTURE OF <code>pasien_polis</code>]

[image: STRUCTURE OF <code>polyclinics</code>]

Comment: Please show your table structure for both tables (pasien_polis, polyclinics)

Comment: I have updated the post and posted the table structures. @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this :

```
    $pasienpoli = DB::table('pasien_polis')
                        ->join('polyclinics','polyclinics.id','=','pasien_polis.polyclinic_id')
                        ->where([
                         ['pasien_polis.polyclinic_id', '=', $id],
                         ['pasien_polis.created_at', '=', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString()]])
                       ->get();
```

Hope this help for you !

Comment: still get the same result. i tried to change this polyclinics.id to id, i got mysql error. in aptana it says syntax error, but i think that's not the real problem. I feel i have set the ralations corectly but still don't get it working properly.

Comment: I accepted this answer because i got it working by modifying this answer. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED by modifying `@AddWeb Solution Pvt`'s answer (thanks a bunch for that).
here is my final working query:

```
$pasienpoli = DB::table('pasien_polis')
  ->join('polyclinics','polyclinics.id','=','pasien_polis.polyclinic_id')
  ->where([
  ['pasien_polis.polyclinic_id', '=', $id],
  [DB::raw('DATE(pasien_polis.created_at)'), '=', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString()]
  ])->get();
```